# Trouble installing rqt features (from source) in Raspbian Jessie in a Minimal ROS Installation

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, I have been trying to install rqt features (such as `rqt_plot` and `rqt_graph`) in a `Minimal` ROS installation (not the full desktop) my Raspberry Pi 2 from source. I have been resolving dependencies all night but now I am stuck. When the package `rqt_gui_cpp` is being built with `catkin_make` , the following error keeps creeping up. What should i do ?

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'qt_gui_cpp'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp)
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
CMake Error at qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
any of the following names:

  Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
  qt5widgets-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
 been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:7390: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233673/trouble-installing-rqt-features-(from-source)-in-raspbian-jessie-in-a-minimal-ros-installation./) by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdep rule for Debian Jessie has recently been fixed ( https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/29a8e801294a64381f9ce43128657482df8ca923). Please make sure to use the latest versions and install all dependencies with rosdep again.

In your case you are missing `qtbase5-dev` which provides the CMake config files for `Qt5Widgets`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-05-07**:
Thank you for the quick answer. Installing qtbase5-dev solved my problem.